# Angular RxJs - how to refactor a static parameter to use a stream instead?

Tags: angular, stream, rxjs, observable

I am trying to find how to remove the second static parameter in this method so I can retrieve it instead from an existing observable:

```
  duplicateTemplate(name: string, id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._authService
      .post(
        `templates/${id}/duplicate`,
        this.newTemplate(name)
      )
      .map(response => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }
```

I want to remove it so callers don't need to know it (as this code lives in a service which already contains the existing template as an observable):

```
  duplicateTemplate(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return
      this.getSelected.subscribe(t => <pass this along>)
      // how can I give 't' to the below code
      this._authService
        .post(
          `templates/${t.id}/duplicate`,
          this.newTemplate(name)
        )
        .map(response => {
          return response.json();
        });
  }
```

I am also wondering if this is the correct way to solve this UX problem, which is:

1. The user clicks in the UI to 'select' an existing Template
2. The component calls a service to `setSelected` (a `Subject<Template>`)
3. Then the user enters a new name, and clicks confirm
4. The component then calls the above `duplicateTemplate` method
5. This uses the id of the selected template to call the API to duplicate it with a new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap`, perhaps?

```
template$.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(templateValue => this._authService.post(
        `templates/${id}/duplicate`,
        templateValue,
    ),
    map(// etc.
```

---

**EDIT (by OP)**

The above helped me reach a solution BUT I had to change the getSelected to use a `BehaviorSubject` (as it was currently of type `Subject`).

```
  duplicateTemplate(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getSelected.take(1).switchMap(t => {
      return this._authService
        .post(
          `templates/${t.id}/duplicate`,
          this.newTemplate(name)
        )
        .map(response => {
          return response.json();
        });
    })
  }
```

Comment: SwitchMap works when I change the stream to a BehaviorSubject instead of Subject.

Comment: `ReplaySubject` would do, too.

Comment: @Enthu I had a quick look but that is a lot of code to investigate and understand. Sorry but I do not have time for such an investigation. Maybe try www.codementor.com and look for Angular expert who offers 15/20 minutes free.

Comment: @Enthu sorry it is 1am here and I am going to bed. Try codementor